# Loop through a finite language described by regex in python

Tags: python, regex

The given input is a regex that describe a finite language. Is there a simple way to enumerate the language in python (or in other programming language)?

The following is what I expect:

Psuedocode:

```
for x in r'[a-c]':
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: You need to use the `re` python module I believe.

Comment: i deleted my answer since i misunderstood the question.  For anyone else who reads it the same way I did - what @FrankHuang is looking for is a way to generate all possible strings that his regular expression can match.

Comment: @JEarls, thank you for the reinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with the built-in `re` module.

Instead, what you need to do is build your own regular expression parser and use that to generate your language.

Just to see if I could do it, I made a *basic* regular expression parser and generator.  The code is 410 lines long including some minimal documentation, so probably too big to fit here, so it's in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jearls/a8235e13c21f2c2a283dd4080f3cee17).

Sample output:

```
$ python regen.py '[a-c]'
'a'
'b'
'c'
```

Sequence of items:

```
$ python regen.py '[a-c][1-5]'
'a1'
'a2'
'a3'
'a4'
'a5'
'b1'
'b2'
'b3'
'b4'
'b5'
'c1'
'c2'
'c3'
'c4'
'c5'
```

Alternate items:

```
$ python regen.py '[a-c]|[1-5]'
'a'
'b'
'c'
'1'
'2'
'3'
'4'
'5'
```

Infinite operators are capped at 5 repetitions...

```
$ python regen.py 'a*'
''
'a'
'aa'
'aaa'
'aaaa'
'aaaaa'
```

but finite operators are not:

```
$ python regen.py 'a{3,6}'
'aaa'
'aaaa'
'aaaaa'
'aaaaaa'
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I need. Are you doing this with DFA? I guess it'll take me some time to understand the code.

Comment: Not really, although it could be transformed into one.  I actually build a parse tree for the regular expression, where each node type in the parse tree knows how to generate its own possibilities in combination with its children.